# jquery switch images based on radio ID with pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is the radio selection:

```
<ul id="radio-attribute" class="radio-attribute">
    <li class="radio-attribute">
        <label for="1" class="radio-attribute">
            <input type="radio" id="1" name="Choose color" value="36" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
            <img src="images/Red.jpg" alt="Red SE1017" title=" Red SE1017 " width="25" height="25" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="radio-attribute">
        <label for="2" class="radio-attribute">
            <input type="radio" id="2" name="Choose color" value="157" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
            <img src="images/Orange.jpg" alt="Orange" title=" Orange " width="25" height="25" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine.

I am looking to swap the images displayed based on the radio selection.  The radio selection will vary so I was planning to use the id for this.

The display container:

```
<div id="piGal" style="float: left;">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/images/main.jpg">
        <img src="images/main.jpg" alt=" Seals" title=" main image " width="250" height="106" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This displays fine on initial load.

I am trying to use an array I build dynamically with php so the javascript looks like this:

```
function change_image(radioID) {
    var images = ["main.jpg", "Red.jpg", "Orange.jpg"];
    document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = "<img src='images/'+ images[radioID]>";
}
```

I can get this working using AJAX, but it will not allow me to have a pop up with it, rather will open in a new page.  I have been trying to use this so I can use a modal.  I am very new to javascript like this though.

Comment: Wait. You want this function open a popup or just change a dom Object on value change?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this form should be sent to php I **strongly discourage you** to use names with spaces. I once experienced some kind of problems with php and I still don’t know why.

Your problem might be in `change_image()`:

```
function change_image(radioID) {
    var images = ["main.jpg", "Red.jpg", "Orange.jpg"];
document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = "<img src=\"images/"+ images[radioID] +"\" />";
}
```

You haven’t generated the right HTML code for the img. You were making a mess with HTML attribute quotes and JavaScript string quotes. Try it now.

Now if

```
image[radioID] == "main.jpg"
```

JavaScript will generate

```
<img src="images/main.jpg" />
```

Which is correct HTML. Your code would generate the string as is, which is not correct HTML, and your browser fails silently.

**EDIT: ** to open the popup:

```
window.open("main.jpg", "imgWindow",
     "location=no,width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes,top=100,left=700,resizable=no");
```

The first argument is the URL of the file to open, the second argument is a unique name for the window (if you open another file with the same window name, the same window will be selected), the third argument is a list of parameters separated by commas (I guess the names are intuitive). You can put it in a function callable on the onClick event of the img tag your creating in `change_image()`

Comment: That is perfect, and is where I was to start with, I do need to implement the pop up and is why I switched from a different solution that queried the database on each radio click to this solution.   Is there a way to implement a pop up (I have jquery loaded) with the image with this?

Comment: So you now need to generate an image from the database?

Comment: No, I pull the images from the database, these images are associated with color swatches, which switch the image based on the radio, all of this is working and was (I used AJAX to query the database on each radio click before), I need to put a pop up though into this so that when the switched image is clicked a pop up, the pop up is where I am having issues as it was just opening the image in a new window...

Comment: Did you take a look to window.open() to open a popup? You can load a page containing the image or the image itself if you don’t need to put any other information, that’s up to you

Comment: Yes, basically what I am trying to do is load image names from the database, show color swatches (radio buttons) on each click of the color swatch, change the image (have that functional now with the above), and on each change of image allow for it to be clicked and open a modal box.  it is the opening of the modal (which will just be the image enlarged) is where I am not getting to far.  I have had this image switch on the radio using various methods, just no luck with the modal opening for each image loaded though the above events.

Comment: Updated, see if it’s what you’re looking for

Comment: Not really what I was thinking of, as an example, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp is what I am trying to achieve, with the image array used to select the image to open.